# $S^n$ admit a real polarization $D\subset TS^n$?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, mp.mathematical-physics, sg.symplectic-geometry, smooth-manifolds

When the $n$-sphere, $S^n$,admit a real polarization $D\subset TS^n$

Comment: What is the definition of real polarization in this setting? Usually I have seen that it is a Lagrangian fibration satisfying some properties, but that doesn't fit with what you've written.

Comment: here is the definition of real polarization in sense of geometric quantization http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~jthomas7/GeomQuant/Lecture4.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this only would make sense when $n$ is even, but there are two problems:  First, except when $n=1$, the $2n$-sphere does not carry any symplectic structure.  Second, the tangent bundle of the $2n$-sphere has no nontrivial subbundles anyway.  (The reason is that $TS^{2n}$ has nonzero Euler class, so it cannot be written as $P\oplus Q$ where $P$ and $Q$ have positive rank, since these two bundles would have to be orientable and have zero Euler class.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, can you explain more the last two lines, it is a bit mass for me. :)

Comment: If you don't know about the Euler class of an oriented vector bundle, I suggest that you take a look at the chapter on this in Milnor and Stasheff's *Characteristic Classes*, where the Euler class and the Euler product formula are explained clearly and simply.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am stadying this book now. Happy new year